# AngularJS Allow-Origin to WebApi2

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, same-origin-policy

I want to host my API on a separate domain. I have configured my auth-interceptor for token in angular with a bearer:

```
config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token');
```

In my My WebApi2 I have configured the WebApiConfig with cors.

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://mydomain.com", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

And in web.config of the API I also included:

```
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
</customHeaders>
```

I still can´t access the api due to origin not allowed. Can I add something more in my header of the auth-interceptor in angular or what do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

In web.config of API, include the below mentioned code:

```
<system.webServer>    
    <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
 <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
     </system.webServer>
```

I hope this helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

your Angular.js interceptor settings are ok.
I've got a public project with your same scenario, with OAuth+Owin authentication. The steps I followed are:

1. Installation of Microsoft.Owin.Cors library
2. Creation of custom section config to enable/config CORS
3. Creation of [custom CORS Policy class](https://github.com/williamverdolini/discitur-api/blob/sprint5/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L107) (with the origins to enable)
4. [Setup of CORS policy](https://github.com/williamverdolini/discitur-api/blob/sprint5/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L67) depending on configurations

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue before and what worked for me was to remove the settings from the web.config and just leave the configuration settings in the `WebApiConfig` class

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664988/yet-another-put-post-and-cors-issue-angularjs-web-api-2/21667606#21667606) for more details