# Laravel cross site AJAX post with session. Working but with JavaScript error?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, cross-domain, laravel-5.3

I'm doing a cross site AJAX post to a laravel website while maintaining the session. This is the JS on the client website and the laravel middleware on my server.

**Client js**

```
var formData = new FormData(); 
formData.append('Referer', document.referrer);
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("post", "https://mywebsite.com/record"); 
xmlHttp.withCredentials = true;
xmlHttp.send(formData);
```

**Server middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
return $next($request)
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',         $request->header('Origin'))
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credential',     'true')
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods',        'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
}
```

It seems to be working fine in the 3 browsers I've tested it in so far however it does seem to throw up an error of

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mywebsite.com/record. Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials. Origin 'http://clientwebsite.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This is what the server sends back in fiddler.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://clientwebsite.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credential: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

Two questions.

Question 1

First I can't understand why its saying its not working when I know it is? I can see the requests making it to the server then populating my database and I can see them being sent in fiddler.

Question 2

There is obviously something wrong with the headers but I'm not sure what?

I can see someone else has had the same issue but I wasn't able to make sense of the answer and I tried changing the header to "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials = true".

[Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269488/credentials-flag-is-true-but-the-access-control-allow-credentials)

Comment: U have a typo, u forgot the 's' in credentials

Comment: I'm an idiot. Excuse me while I flog myself sir. 

Thanks! :-)