# how to post to soap web service from angularjs?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, web-services, soap, asp.net-2.0

I am moved to a soap Web service `ver 3.5`. The post request are working fine for .net 4.5v. But while post data to service i am getting errors:

At browser

```
Error: OPTIONS http://localhost/webserv/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/webserv/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld. Invalid HTTP status code 500
```

When i saw the details it is showing this

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: obj.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

My implementation is as:

```
$http({
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://localhost/webserv/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld',
 datatype: 'json',
 data:JSON.stringify({obj:details})
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
 }).success(function(data,status, headers, config){
   if(status == '200'){
     alert(data.d);
   }
 }).error(function(data,status, headers, config){});
```

And at service

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string HelloWorld(Details obj)
{
   return  JsonConvert.SerializeObject((new Helper()).GetDetails(obj.Id);
}
```

inside web config:

```
 <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
```

How could i be able to call post request and get result in json format?

Answer (score 0):

From this 
Error: `OPTIONS http://localhost/webserv/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld`  I can assume you are facing CORS issue.
There are two ways to solve these issue:

1. On server side you need to add CORS headers. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458444/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-iis7) for more information.
2. Use Chrome browser:
   Open chrome browser using following command and browse to your page from where this service is getting called.

   chrome.exe --disable-web-security