# WCF handling CORS & Options VERB

Tags: wcf, iis, cross-domain, cors

I have a wcf service hosted on IIS. 
Almost all the documents say that to enable cors, you should handle the OPTIONS VERB. (Pre-Flight Requests)

I have a method whose signatures are :

```
[OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionManager))]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            UriTemplate = "PostLog")]
        string PostLog(List<LoginEntry> LoginLog);
```

I have created an attribute deriving from IServiceBehavior & hooked up this Class to my service & handled BeforeSendReply method to add Acces Control methods as :

```
public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
{

    var httpHeader = reply.Properties["httpResponse"] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
    httpHeader.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    httpHeader.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    httpHeader.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type");

}
```

This did not help me when i created a testcall in firefox. So i took it out from here & added this in Global.asax file as

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                           HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {

                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

            }
        }
```

I could see in firefox 403 Error & my headers not being present. 
so i went ahead & put those headers in IIS settings (Custom headers Tab).  (I took the risk of sending those in each response). 
Now i can see those headers in response in firefox, but I am still getting 403 Error. 
This is the response header :

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 1758
Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2015 14:47:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Accept
```

I also tried Changing to Method="*" in WebInvoke. but still could not get it to work.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally Got it to Work. 
This post helped me out.

[enabling cross-origin resource sharing on IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458444/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-iis7/16229340#16229340)

Turns out that the problem was in IIS 6 Site settings.

Solved it by the following steps :

In IIS, Select Site -> RightClick (Properties) ->

Under the Directory Tab Select Configuration Button.

Under the **Mappings Tab.** Search for Extension (.svc) 
Click on Edit. Search for Label "Limit Verbs To".

Previous Value was "GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG"

**Replaced It With "GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,OPTIONS"**

Also, I removed all those headers configs from IIS (coz I was already managing them Global.asax).

Comment: This was a lifesaver. We still have a few classic asp pages on an IIS 6 server and I was going crazy trying to figure this out. Thank you!