# Apache Cordova error uploading cropped image to server from IOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, wcf, visual-studio-cordova

On my IOS mobile application I am taking picture and then select a picture from gallery. After selecting this picture I am using **ng-img-crop.js** to crop this image and **without saving this cropped image**, trying to upload it to a server, the server side is C# WCF. (In this particular example I am trying to upload local IIS) But I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: {"code":1,"source":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE...","target":"http://11.111.11.111/wcf/OCRService.svc/upload","http_status":null,"body":null,"exception":null}
app.js (76,24)
```

Should I save this cropped image to the gallery before uploading to the server? Is there any way to upload it without saving?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src 'self' http://11.111.11.111/wcf/OCRService.svc/upload 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

    <title>LoTTo</title>-->

    <!-- LoTTo references -->
    <link href="css/ionicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/ng-img-crop.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ng-img-crop.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .cropArea {
            background: #E4E4E4;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
        }
        .croppedArea {
            background: #E4E4E4;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 300px;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-light">
        <h1 class="title">LoTTo</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController" padding="true">
        <button class="button button-full button-balanced icon-right ion-ios-camera" ng-click="takePhoto()">
            Resim Çek
        </button>

        <button class="button button-full button-balanced icon-right ion-images" ng-click="choosePhoto()">
            Resim Seç
        </button>
        <center>
            <div class="cropArea">

                <img-crop image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage" chargement="'Loading'"
                          area-type="rectangle"
                          area-min-size="50"
                          result-image-format="image/jpeg"
                          result-image-quality="1"
                          result-image-size="{w:300, h:50}"></img-crop>

            </div>
            <div ng-show="myImage !== undefined">Gönderilecek Resim:</div>
            <div class="croppedArea"><img ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}" ng-show="myImage !== undefined" id="image" /></div>


        </center>
        <button class="button button-full button-balanced icon-right ion-images" ng-click="upload(myCroppedImage);" ng-if="myImage !== undefined">
            Resim Yükle
        </button>

    </ion-content>    
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ngImgCrop', 'ngFileUpload'])

.controller("ExampleController", ['$scope', '$cordovaCamera', 'Upload', '$timeout', '$cordovaFileTransfer', function ($scope, $cordovaCamera, Upload, $timeout, $cordovaFileTransfer) {

    $scope.takePhoto = function () {
        var options = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 300,
            targetHeight: 300,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
            $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert(err);
        });
    }

    $scope.choosePhoto = function () {
        var options = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 300,
            targetHeight: 300,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
            $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
            $scope.myImage = $scope.imgURI;

        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert(err);
        });
    }

    $scope.myCroppedImage = '';

    $scope.upload = function (dataUrl) {

    Upload.upload({

        url: 'http://192.168.1.20/wcf/upload',
        data: {
            file: Upload.dataUrltoBlob(dataUrl)
        },

    }).then(function (response) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.result = response.data;
            console.log(response.data);
            alert(response.data);
        });
        console.log(response.data);
    }, function (response) {
        if (response.status > 0) $scope.errorMsg = response.status
            + ': ' + response.data;
        alert(response.status);
    });

}

}]);
```

**Edit 1: How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to my mobile app?**

**Edit 2: Changed the upload section**

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

This example might help you:
Check this jsfiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/xxo3sk41/1/][1]

code :

```
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload', 'ngImgCrop']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
$scope.upload = function (dataUrl) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
        data: {
            file: Upload.dataUrltoBlob(dataUrl)
        },
    }).then(function (response) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.result = response.data;
        });
    }, function (response) {
        if (response.status > 0) $scope.errorMsg = response.status 
            + ': ' + response.data;
    }, function (evt) {
        $scope.progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
    });
}
}]);
```

Comment: I am getting this error ***Failed to load resource: The request timed out.* @Tushar

Comment: At home I am getting this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
upload (0,0)

Comment: I am using local IIS 7.5 and installed asp, isapi etc. Now I am getting 0 from the response. What does it mean? There is no error log on IIS. If 0 means successful, there is no file on the uploaded folder.

Comment: I will try this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458444/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-iis7) and let you know.

Comment: @Cenk, is that issue solved or are you still not able to find a solution ?

Comment: not resolved, still working on it. I think there is CORS issue.Should I use Upload.http instead?

Comment: @Cenk, the problem might be here : var targetPath = croppedImg;

Comment: I already changed the upload section as you suggested but still getting 0 response. Please check my edit 2.

Comment: $scope.upload = function (dataUrl) { ....
This method requires a fileUrl, but you are passing a data object, not url.

Comment: I am trying to send the cropped image without saving it to the gallery. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Using this plugin you can't do that probably. Use other plugin that has that feature. For this plugin you may delete the file after successful upload. That way the file will be uploaded and it won't be there after upload.

Comment: Hi @Tushar, can I send this picture to a web service on a server in order to OCR this image and return a result? Is this possible?

Comment: Yes why not. It's possible. The server needs to process the image and then return the result as response.

Comment: can you suggest another plugin @Tushar in order to send picture to a web service and return the result from the service without saving the cropped image.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/jcesarmobile/PhonegapOCRPlugin and https://github.com/matiastucci/ionic-ocr-example

Comment: don't get me wrong but I already have a OCR service. I just want to send image to this service and get a response from this service. How can I do it with my example above?