# Orchestrator Authentication not working with Javascript XHR request

Tags: javascript, cors, uipath, preflight

I try to build a website where I can internally control our UiPath Orchestrator. We are using an on-premise Orchestrator.

The connection was firstly tested in Postman/curl:

```
curl --location --request POST '{{url}}/api/Account/Authenticate' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "tenancyName": "{{tenantName}}",
    "usernameOrEmailAddress": "{{usernameOrEmailAddress}}",
    "password": "{{password}}"
}'
```

This gives me back the `authtoken` without any issue. Perfect.

Then I tried to implement that `curl` as `XHR` in Javascript:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({"tenancyName":"...","usernameOrEmailAddress":"...","password":"..."});
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.withCredentials = true;
      xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        if(this.readyState === 4) {
          console.log(this.responseText);
        }
      });
      xhr.open("POST", "https://.../api/account/authenticate");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      xhr.send(data);
```

But Firefox and Chrome are trying to preflight. So I get a 404 statuscode back:

Firefox:

[image: firefox]

Chrome:

[image: chrome]

I'm confused now how to fix it. Actually it is obviously a CORS issue. So I tried to set:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
```

on our IIS7 server. Without any change.

Also I tried to set this setting to allow everything on the Node.js server and on the XHR request. But 404 stays.

Then I tried using Chrome and Firefox Plugins to disable CORS. But 404 stays.

And again in Postman it works perfectly since the first try. So it just a CORS issue. But I want to let CORS enable, maybe just configure it in a way that specific server are allowed. How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [enabling cross-origin resource sharing on IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458444/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-iis7)

Comment: I added the both lines, without any change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to **disable cors** on IIS10.

But be sure that this is only for testing and only kind of secure when you run it non-public! Later you should enable it again and restrict to your used domains.

First [install the Cors module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module).

And the second step is adding this line to the web.config file of the IIS10 server:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
          <add origin="*">
            <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
          </add>
        </cors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the non-preflight request:

```
  var data = "tenancyName=...&usernameOrEmailAddress=...&password=...";
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if(this.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  });

  xhr.open("POST", "https://url/api/account/authenticate");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send(data);
```

As `"Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` is one of the non-preflight we simply dodge the CORS mechanics with it. And for sure the `data` variable was changed so the `JSON.stringify` is gone now.

As the UiPath Orchestrator server is in a private Azure environment, this is not a huge security issue at all.

Anyway solutions that disable the CORS completely on the IIS7 server are still welcome.